# Как открыть сведения о компьютере через Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Как можно сделать код, который откроет о системе (меню, где показана система, процессор и ОЗУ)
на Python 3.10.

```
bl = Button(systek, image = systessk, command = systeo)                                  
bl.place(x=1,y=1, width=256, height=144)

def systeo():
..............(что здесь надо написать?)
```

Comment: Запускайте [команды](https://www.tecmint.com/commands-to-collect-system-and-hardware-information-in-linux/) и выбирайте из их вывода то, что считаете нужным

Comment: В какой операционной системе хоть? И о каком меню речь?

Comment: Добрый день, на windows 10/11  там где написаны характеристики пк процессор и тд....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это окно открывается командой:

```
explorer shell:::{BB06C0E4-D293-4F75-8A90-CB05B6477EEE}
```

Запустить в Питоне

```
import os
os.system("explorer shell:::{BB06C0E4-D293-4F75-8A90-CB05B6477EEE}")
```

Если интересна теория, то это окно есть COM-объект (Component Object Model). COM объекты открываются через CLSID.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Галочку поставил